# How does depth work in a frustum environment?

Tags: opengl-es

I need some help understanding the basics of a frustum transformation. Mainly, how depth works.

The following uses a viewport of 768x1024. Using an Orthogonal projection and a square of 768x768 (z defaults to 0) with no translation or scaling, and a viewport of `glViewport(0, 0, 768, 1024)` this square easily fills the width of the frame:

[image]

Now when I change the project to a frustum and mess with the z translation, the square scales appropriately due to the perspective changes.

Here is the same square in such an environment:

[image]

I can play with this z translation, as well as the near and far parameters of the frustum matrix and make the square change is apparent onscreen size accordingly. Fine.

But what I cannot figure out is the obvious relationship between its onscreen size and these depth parameters.

For example, suppose I want to use a frustum but have the square fill the frame width, as in my first example image above. How to achieve this?

I would think that if the z translation matched the `near` plane, then you'd essentially have a square "right in front of the camera", filling the frame. But I cannot figure a way to achieve this. **If my near is `1` and my z translation is `-1`, then the square should be sitting right on the near plane itself** (right?!) , filling the width of the frame (where the frustum's left and right planes are the same as the orthogonal projection).

I could paste a bunch of code here to show what I'm doing but I think the concept here is clear. I just want to figure out where the near plane actually is, how to situate something on it, as this will help me understand how the frustum is working.

---

Okay here is the relevant code I'm using, where `width=768` and `height=1024`.

My vertex shader is the simple `gl_Position=Projection*Modelview*Position;`

My projection matrix (frustum) is thus:

`Frustum(-width/2, width/2, -height/2, height/2, 1,10);`

This function is:

```
    static Matrix4<T> Frustum(T left, T right, T bottom, T top, T near, T far)
{
    T a = 2 * near / (right - left);
    T b = 2 * near / (top - bottom);
    T c = (right + left) / (right - left);
    T d = (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
    T e = - (far + near) / (far - near);
    T f = -2 * far * near / (far - near);
    Matrix4 m;
    m.x.x = a; m.x.y = 0; m.x.z = 0; m.x.w = 0;
    m.y.x = 0; m.y.y = b; m.y.z = 0; m.y.w = 0;
    m.z.x = c; m.z.y = d; m.z.z = e; m.z.w = -1;
    m.w.x = 0; m.w.y = 0; m.w.z = f; m.w.w = 1;
    return m;
}
```

My square is just two 2d triangles with a default z=0, and an x range from left as -768/2 and right edge at 768/2. The square is clearly working properly as my first image above shows, using the orthogonal projection. (Though I switched to the frustum projection for this question)

To draw the square, I translate the Modelview with:

`Translate(0, 0, -1);`

Using:

```
static Matrix4<T> Translate(T x, T y, T z)
{
    Matrix4 m;
    m.x.x = 1; m.x.y = 0; m.x.z = 0; m.x.w = 0;
    m.y.x = 0; m.y.y = 1; m.y.z = 0; m.y.w = 0;
    m.z.x = 0; m.z.y = 0; m.z.z = 1; m.z.w = 0;
    m.w.x = x; m.w.y = y; m.w.z = z; m.w.w = 1;
    return m;
}
```

As you can see, the translation should put the square on the near plane, yet it looks like this:

[image]

If I translate instead of -1.01 just to be sure I avoid near clipping, the result is the same. If I do not translate, thus z=0, the square does not appear, as you'd expect, since it would be behind the camera.

Comment: Looking e.g. [here](http://earth.uni-muenster.de/~joergs/opengl/glFrustum.html), I don't see a constant `1` at `m.w.w` in the frustum matrix. It should be `0`.

Comment: Thanks for ignoring my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your frustum matrix, `m.w.w` should be 0, not 1.  This will fix your problem.

But, the mistake isn't your fault.  It's my fault!  I'm actually the one who wrote that code in the first place, and unfortunately it has proliferated.  It's an errata in my book (*iPhone 3D Programming*), which is where it first appeared.

Feeling very guilty about this!

Comment: no problem, and indeed that fixed it. mistakes happen. thanks for pointing it out. is there an errata page for your book, or perhaps this is the only inaccuracy?

Comment: Yes, the errata page is [here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596804831) -- the frustum bug is noted at the bottom of the page.  Hopefully it's the only error that really causes a lot of grief!

Comment: thanks philip, the book is really great overall though I must admit some of the concepts are exceptionally challenging for a newbie and I still struggle to find online explanations in the vain of "explain to me like I'm only 10 years old". the quaternion stuff in particular, how to use them properly, it's still confusing.

Comment: i managed to resolve my confusion on quaternions (most of it, anyway, for now), by watching a free iTunes University lecture on computer graphics from UC Berkeley. Definitely opened up the idea. But I digress.

Comment: I've added a question about your matrix library here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583343/are-these-functions-column-major-or-row-major

Answer (score 2):

> If my near is 1 and my z translation is -1, then the square should be sitting right on the near plane itself (right?!)

Yes

> , filling the width of the frame (where the frustum's left and right planes are the same as the orthogonal projection).

Not neccesarily. The near plane has the extents given with the *left*, *right*, *bottom* and *top* parameters of glFrustum. A rectangle going to exactly those bounds will snugly fit the viewport when being placed at the near plane distance.

Comment: Seems that you support what I'm saying: if left and right planes have x values of -100 and 100, respectively, then a square ranging from x=-100 to x=100 and positioned on the near plane itself should indeed fill the *width* of the viewport, right? (assuming viewport width is 200 in this case)

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: Exactly. Of course it may happen that if it's exactly on the near place, it may get near-clipped and thus become "invisible".

Comment: hmm, my experience is not working out that way. I have my `near` set to `1` in my frustum, and my 2d square is translated to a z of `-1` and it still "sits back" from the near plane, well padded on all sides as if it is further away.

Comment: problem solved. the frustum matrix in the book i was using had a typo.