# Vector-Matrix multiplication order can affect performance?

Tags: math, matrix, graphics, 3d

This is not a row-major vs column-major question. This is an order of calculation question as pertaining to performance, based on the associative property of matrix multiplication: `A(BC)=(AB)C`

If I have 2 matrices, `A` and `B`, and a vector `v` and I want to multiply them all together in a certain order, for example `ABv`, I can do `(AB)v` or `A(Bv)`.

It occurs to me, programmatically, that I get better performance from far fewer calculations if I use the second method and always multiply a matrix with a vector.

For example, if we are dealing with 4x4 matrices:

`AB` results in 16 individual calculations, a new matrix, each result is from a dot product

`Matrix*vector` results in 4 calculations, each from a dot product

Therefore:

`(AB)v` is 16+4 dot product calculations=20

`A(Bv)` is two matrix-vector products, or 4+4 dot product calculations = 8

Am I thinking correctly? This suggests that performing many many vector-matrix expressions like this will dramatically improve performance if I start with the vector each time?

Thus it would make sense to structure a matrix library that performs based on vector*matrix left-to-right calculation order (even if you choose to notate right-to-left with column-major formatting) since multiplying a vector with matrix products is very common in graphics.

Comment: andand and tmyklebu explained it correctly already. As a further insight I'd to add, that in computer graphics, especially when using a programmable transformation pipeline, one normally deals with quasi static matrices (the matrices are constants for large bunch of vectors). Often you have a compund View · Model matrix `MV` and a projection matrix `P` procomputed. `MV` usually condenses a large number of transformations and the intermediary product `MV · v` is required for certain calculations (illumination). So effectively it boils down to your `A·(B·v)` case.

Comment: But, there is one important development in modern graphics hardware (GPUs): While GPUs used to be vector architectures in the early days (Shader Model 2), Shader Model 3 GPUs are in fact (super)scalar architectures, where vectorization happens by performing regular scalar operations in parallel. And this changes the numbers a bit. However inner/dot products are still executed faster from a dot product operation, than doing the scalar dance manually.

Comment: @datenwolf Thank you, I have asked an additional question that pertains to how the shader performs this calculation directly with regards to eficiency

Comment: @datenwolf I don't know if you are on the OpenGL forums, and perhaps I should put this as a question on here, but I know you have implemented your own linear algebra library and you probably have some insight on this particular conundrum I've come across: http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/181867-Structuring-a-matrix-library?p=1251455#post1251455

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within the limited context of a single operation of the matrices and a single vector involved, you and tmyklebu have it right.  However, there is usually a larger context you need to be aware of before you apply it in practice.  That issue revolves around how often **A** and **B** change relative to how often *v* changes.  If **A** and **B** are relatively static (they don't change very often) compared with *v*, you may be better off precomputing **AB** and applying it to whatever value *v* happens to have.

Furthermore, in practice, there is some geometry comprised of multiple vectors which can be more efficiently transformed and computed together by first computing **AB** and then applying that transformation to all of the vectors in the geometry.

Comment: +1 for noting the case of a static AB applied over a variety of different vectors, as is indeed often the case in graphics.

Answer (score 3):

Your thinking is correct, yes.  Finding the optimal way to multiply a chain of matrices is a [famous example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication) of a problem solvable using dynamic programming.

Comment: That's interesting; since in 3D graphics we are usually dealing with 4x4 matrices in our calculations and 4-element vectors that are typically at one end of the chain, it would seem this problem is a bit easier to diagnose and results in the simple observation that always starting with the vector and ensuring that every calculation involves a vector is the right way to go.

Comment: @Fellowshee: Yes, but outside 3D graphics, big matrices are rather more common :)  (Of course, I've never seen anyone *use* matrix chain multiplication as anything other than a handy DP example.)