# Does OpenGL internally calculate shaders starting with the vector?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, glsl

Typically you see an OpenGL shader calculation structure as such:

`gl_Position=ProjectionMatrix * ModelViewMatrix * positionVector`

That is, `matrix*matrix*vector`

As discovered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952546/vector-matrix-multiplication-order-can-affect-performance), calculation efficiency of a matrix chain is completely controllable, and it is in fact more efficient to begin the calculations with the vector.

Now the typical Shader calculation as noted above assume column-major ordering, since the vector is on the right. What I would like to know is how does OpenGL actually perform the above calculation? In a column-major system, the *order* (not the notation) of a `matrix*matrix*vector` calculation is `vector*matrix*matrix` since it flows right-to-left.

What is confusing is that the shader code, like any programming code, is written left-to-right and the standard mathematical order of operations is assumed. Thus it would imply that the shader is calculating the vector *last* and thus performing inefficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a column-major system, the order (not the notation) of a matrix*matrix*vector calculation is vector*matrix*matrix since it flows right-to-left.

No, it isn't. The order of operation is exactly what you wrote: matrix*matrix*vector. While you can *conceptually* reverse it in order to follow the vertex through the transform pipeline, that's just your conceptual perspective of the sequence of transformations. The order of the mathematical operations remains the same.

Matrix multiplication is not [commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property); you cannot rearrange the order like that. But it is *[associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property)*. Which means that `(matrix*matrix)*vector` is equivalent to `matrix*(matrix*vector)`. The latter will be computed more optimally.

Will your compiler perform the latter computation instead of the former? That depends entirely on the quality of your compiler. But putting a few parenthesis in the right place will ensure that it does.

Comment: Interesting that you don't see more examples in shader tutorials of `matrix*(matrix*vector)` when it is clearly more efficient. It's such a simple thing to do, to add parenthesis, and it could make a big difference in performance. Why isn't more well-known to suggest this?

Comment: @Fellowshee: Because it's not "clearly more efficient". The efficiency difference can be zero, because the compiler could (very easily) detect this and do it the right way. The parenthesis only help if the compiler is bad. Also, tutorials aren't about *efficiency*; they're about explaining stuff. So you shouldn't be taking performance tips from them unless the tutorial is *about* performance.

Comment: @Fellowshee Most of the time they are just that, tutorials showing the principal concepts and not aiming for each and every performance optimization. And more often than not you pre-multiply matrices on the CPU before uploading anyway, so you rather have `projectionModelview * vector`. And other times you need intermediate results anyway `vec4 eye = modelview * vector; ...lighting...; gl_Position = projection * eye;`. So I don't think this is really such a heavy problem in practice. I rarely see `matrix * matrix * vector` except maybe in, well, tutorials.